# merge Twitter Boostrap element styling into any element

Tags: css, sass, less

I am working with Drupal and with that, I don't always have the freedom to add a class by altering a html tag, however. I would like to apply some Twitter Bootstrap styling on an element from my `custom.css` file (the bootstrap css file is loaded, so styling is available).

To illustrate it better, for example, I would like to apply `class="img-polaroid"` (TB base styling) to an `image` that I can interface as `div.someClass` in my `custom css` stylesheet. I don't have simple way to alter the `img` tag to have `class="img-polaroid someClass"`.

I would like to accomplish the same in my `custom` stylesheet. In another words, the merge happens not in the html tag but in the css stylesheet itself. How can I accomplish this with the current technologies in place? Are we there to make this possible?

Thank You

p.s. I am aware of alternatives:
-use JS to append class
-Copy and past the styling of `class="img-polaroid"` into `div.someClass` {...}
But both seem like not so nice solutions

Comment: Your options are like you mentioned, or you can modify the Bootstrap stylesheets (not recommended--core hacks tend to get overwritten at update time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you go about this depends on which CSS Preprocessor you're using.  You must choose one if you want to avoid modifying TB itself or the markup.

## Sass

```
.foo {
    @extend .bar;
}
```

Output:

```
.bar, .foo {
    // styles
}
```

## LESS

```
.foo {
    .bar;
}
```

Output:

```
.bar {
    // styles
}

.foo {
    // styles
}
```

Comment: Thank you cimmanon. Sounds like both Less and Sass can accomplish this with extra step of running css processor. If you had to choose to learn between Sass or Less which one would you pick? and why?thanks again

Comment: I used LESS initially, but in my personal opinion, Sass is better in every way.  The ability to use `@extend` was the ultimate selling point for me.  Plus, Sass has Compass.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the part of the CSS code that you want to apply to the element in the bootstrap stylesheet and rewrite the selectors or copy the code to another file with new selectors so the style applies to both

```css
.selector-from-bootrap,
.my-new selector{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you kingdomcreation. Copy and paste is what i am trying avoid. Modifying bootstrap css is out of option since we would like to upgrade bootstrap as often as possible